# In wpf, MVVM light, suddenly simple relaycommand is not working. Where I should start looking?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I was trying to overhaul my old code, but after some point, it started to crash and When I removed several code, the relaycommand is not working.

First, below is working code.

At XAML

```
<Button Name="KPIselectorButton"
        Command="{Binding SelectKPIButtonClick}"
        >
</Button>
```

At MainViewModel class

```
public ICommand SelectKPIButtonClick
{
    get;
    private set;
}

public MainViewModel()
{
    SelectKPIButtonClick = new RelayCommand(SelectKPIButtonClickMethod);
}

private void SelectKPIButtonClickMethod()
{
    Console.Write("start process get KPI information");

    some codes here.

    Console.Write("Get KPI list done.");
}
```

This works normally.

But at another project (Basically same. was working) It doesn't work.

At XAML

```
<Button Name="KPIselectorButton"
        Command="{Binding SelectKPIButtonClick}"
        >
</Button>
```

At MainViewModel

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SelectKPIButtonClick = new RelayCommand(SelectKPIButtonClickMethod);
    }

    public ICommand SelectKPIButtonClick
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    private void SelectKPIButtonClickMethod()
    {
        Console.Write("start process get KPI information");

        Some Codes here.

        Console.Write("Get KPI list done.");
    }
```

As you see, they are just same codes and one work while the others not.
What I did was removing some methods of other logics.

Where should I start to check? I'm totally lost.

Comment: Use a tool such as WPFSnoop - https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf to check that the DataContext of your view (and the button) is correctly set, and for any binding errors.

Comment: Dear Peregrin. Thank you for guide. I installed it but it appears just mouse up and down event happens and no more events are proceed. and I don't know how to go further. I need some more knowledge to make an app for this..  Thank you for help.

Comment: @박영환 did u set the data context?